# Uncanny Addition

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking

```
  ? ?
+   ?
-----
    ?
```

Replace every question mark (`?`) in this addition with a single digit so that the addition is valid and correct. The first (leftmost) question mark in the first (upper) line cannot be zero (`0`).

Credit:

> (2000@[G4G](http://www.gathering4gardner.org/)) Jaime Poniachik (1943–2011)

Comment: Are rot13(artngvir qvtvgf) allowed?

Comment: @Randal'Thor No, they are not

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following in @jafe's footsteps:

> ```
>     I V          I X        X C
>   +   I        +   I      +   X
>  ------   or   -----  or  -----  etc.
>       V            X          C
> ```

Answer (score 6):

One possibility would be using

> some other numbering system than Arabic numerals. The word "digit" [can be used](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/digit) for other systems as well.

For example,

> using [rod numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_rods):
>
>  [image]

Comment: Guvf vf gur evtug nccebnpu. V qba'g xabj, vs ebq ahzrenyf fubhyq pbhag nf n pbeerpg nafjre, ohg vg vf abg gur vagraqrq bar.

Answer (score 2):

> Mixing bases is the first thing I can think of, e.g.:
>  $10_2 + 1_2 = 3_{10}$

Comment: Interesting approach. rot13(Ab onfr punatr)